# How to Parse nested json column to two columns called key and value

Tags: sql, pandas, scala, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a source table with 3 columns. One of the column contains json values. some of the rows contain simple json but some of the rows contain nested json like in image's source table. I want the target table to look like in image attached. could someone help with pyspark code or sql code to put it in databrick?

This json doesn't have a fixed schema. it can be varried in different ways but ultimately its a json.

**source and target tables**

[image: source and target tables]

I am expecting pyspark code for above question.

Here is the sample code used to achieve this.

%py

df1 = spark.sql("select eventId, AppId, eventdata  from tableA)

df1 =  df1 .withColumn("EventData",from_json(df1 .eventdata,MapType(StringType(),StringType())))

df1 = df1 .select(df1.eventId,df1.AppId, explode_outer(df1.EventData))

display(df1)
this resulted in below output
[output][1]

Below is a sample json:

```json
{
   "brote":"AKA",
   "qFilter":"{\"xfilters\":[{\"Molic\":\"or\",\"filters\":[{\"logic\":\"and\",\"field\":\"Name\",\"operator\":\"contains\",\"value\":\"*R-81110\"},{\"logic\":\"and\",\"field\":\"Title\",\"operator\":\"contains\",\"value\":\"*R-81110\"}]}],\"pSize\":200,\"page\":1,\"ignoreConfig\":false,\"relatedItemFilters\":[],\"entityType\":\"WAFADocuments\"}",
   "config":"[\"PR_NMO\"]",
   "title":"All Documents",
   "selected":"PR_NMO",
   "selectedCreateConfig":"PR_NMO",
   "selectedQueryConfigs":[
      "PR_CVO"
   ],
   "selectedRoles":[
      "RL_ZAC_Planner"
   ]
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oftvr.png
```

Comment: Your sample JSON and source and target tables don't match.

Comment: [explode()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) on struct type will give you `key`, `value` columns; but the nested keys like `Orders.id` will be hard to compute if the schema is not fixed.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @Kiran, can you provide any sample code that you have tried so far?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula added the sample code

Answer (score 1):

The below code answered my question.

import json
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import chain, starmap

def flatten(dictionary):
def unpack(parent_key, parent_value):
try:
if parent_value is None or parent_value == '' :
if parent_value is None:
yield parent_key, None
else:
parent_value = ''
elif isinstance(parent_value, str) and (parent_value[0] == '{' or parent_value[0] == '['):
if parent_value[0] == '[':
parent_value = literal_eval(parent_value.replace("null", "None"))
elif parent_value[0] == '{' and ':' in parent_value:
parent_value = json.loads(parent_value)
else:
parent_value = parent_value
if isinstance(parent_value, dict):
for key, value in parent_value.items():
temp1 = parent_key + '.' + key
yield temp1.replace('..', '.'), value
elif isinstance(parent_value, list):
if len(parent_value) == 0:
yield parent_key, "Null"
else:
i = 0
for value in parent_value:
temp2 = parent_key + '['+str(i) + ']'
i += 1
yield temp2, value
else:
yield parent_key, parent_value
except :
return dictionary

```
try :  
    while True:
        dictionary = dict(chain.from_iterable(starmap(unpack, dictionary.items())))
        if not any(isinstance(value, dict) for value in dictionary.values()) and \
            not any(isinstance(value, list) for value in dictionary.values()):
            break
    return dictionary
except : 
    return dictionary
```

#Converting function to UDF
keyvalueUDF = udf(lambda dct: flatten(dct), MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

if we apply the above keyvalueUDF on a DF which has complex json in a column it will give flattend column then using below code we can make key and value columns.

below is the example
#Convert the Raw JSON Event data column to Key & Value columns

MappedJsonEventData = RawJsonEventData.withColumn("EventData",F.from_json(RawJsonEventData.EventData,MapType(StringType(),StringType())))

flattened_df = MappedJsonEventData.select("ApplicationString", "EventName", "EventUuid", "StartDate", keyvalueUDF(MappedJsonEventData.EventData))
flattened_df = flattened_df.withColumnRenamed("(EventData)", "EventData")
.withColumnRenamed("StartDate", "Date")

flattened_df = flattened_df.select("ApplicationString", "EventName", "EventUuid", "Date", F.explode_outer(flattened_df.EventData))

Comment: Can you please format the code consistently in the Answer?

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

- The requirement is hard to achieve as the schema of the nested values is not fixed. To do it with the sample you have given, you can use the following code:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("EventData",from_json(df.EventData,MapType(StringType(),StringType())))
df1 = df1 .select(df1.eventID,df1.AppID, explode_outer(df1.EventData))
#df1.show()

df2 = df1.filter(df1.key == 'orders')

user_schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([
        StructField("id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("type", StringType(), True)
    ])
)

df3 = df2.withColumn("value", from_json("value", user_schema)).selectExpr( "eventID", "AppID", "key","inline(value)")
df3 = df3.melt(['eventID','AppID','key'],['id','type'],'sub_order','val')

req = df3.withColumn('key',concat(df3.key,lit('.'),df3.sub_order))

final_df = df1.filter(df1.key != 'orders').union(req.select('eventID','AppID','key','val'))
final_df.show()
```

[image]

- This might be not possible is the schema would be constantly changing.